# ubuntu - Postfix mail sent from server not logged in mail.log or phpmail.log

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, postfix, sasl

I am having server which hosts 70-80 websites and also using relay server for smtp using postfix using mysql database for domain and email boxes.

I have also activated the phpmail.log for sendmail.

I am getting notification from them that we have received a mail from new sender, which needs to be validated.

What I find is that the sender is not on my domain list.

Now while checking the mail.log or phpmail.log there is no trace of the senderid.

What other steps I can take to dectect the source of this mail from where this script is run?

Comment: Question unclear. What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have updated the php.ini file /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini for the logs, but the logs were not being created.

I am using ISPCONFIG control panel which creates one dedicated php.ini file for each website which was not getting updated.

When I re-synced the website php.ini with the  /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini, I started getting the logs.